# I have a problem in freezing the graph for a CNN model for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I built a CNN model for image classification, I want to use it in an android application so I figured that I need to freeze the graph and save it in .pb format.
I'm trying to use this function to achieve this :

```
MODEL_NAME = 'cnn_model'
def export_model(saver, model, input_node_names, output_node_name):
    tf.train.write_graph(tf.keras.backend.get_session().graph_def, 'out', \
                        MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt')

    saver.save(tf.keras.backend.get_session(), 'out/' + MODEL_NAME  +'.chkp')

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt', None, \
                              False, 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name, \
                              "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0", \
                              'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")

    input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.Open('out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME+ '.pb', "rb") as f:
        input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
            input_graph_def, input_node_names, [output_node_name],
            tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('out/opt_' + MODEL_NAME +'.pb', "wb")as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())

    print("graph saved!")

    return
```

and this is how I called the method :

```
export_model(tf.train.Saver(), classifier , ["conv2d_6_input_2"], "dense_5_2/Softmax")
```

after calling the method five files are produced:

- checkpoint
- cnn_model.chkp.data-00000-of-00001
- cnn_model.chkp.index
- cnn_model.chkp.meta
- cnn_model_graph.pbtxt

but after that this error occurs

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-39ddde1e67a7> in <module>()
----> 1 export_model(tf.train.Saver(), classifier , ["conv2d_6_input_2"], "dense_5_2/Softmax")

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __getitem__(self, i)
   2152 
   2153     def __getitem__(self, i):
-> 2154       return self._inputs[i]
   2155 
   2156   @property

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the CNN layers :

```
# Initialing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolutio Layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu' ,padding='same'))

#step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same'))

# Adding second convolution layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,  3, activation = 'relu' ,padding='same'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same'))

#Adding 3rd Concolution Layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3,  3, activation = 'relu' ,padding='same'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same'))


#Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

#Step 4 - Full Connection
classifier.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(26, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Any help would be so much appreciated as I'm new to machine learning and deep learning and this error has been persisting for days.